# BigQuery referencing subquery under WITH clause in WHERE clause

Tags: google-bigquery

Basically I want to reference the *ListOfIds* subquery defined in the WITH clause directly as a single column table. As an example, I want to achieve something like the following.

```
WITH
  ListOfIds AS (
  SELECT
    Id
  FROM
    ...)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  Id IN ListOfIds
```

The above syntax results in an error of *ListOfIds* is not defined on the line *Id IN ListOfIds*

So far the closest I can get to is the following, and I don't like it for its somewhat complicated and redundant syntax.

```
WITH
  ListOfIds AS (
  SELECT
    Id
  FROM
    ...)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  Id IN (
  SELECT
    Id
  FROM
    ListOfIds)
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly a note. 
You probably don't want to do this.

CTEs (the WITH query) is a bit counterintuitive for people who normally code because it feels like a variable but it is not. 
What actually happens is that [you run the query many times](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) to evaluate it, resulting in poor performance and extra $$ spent.

I recommend you replace this for a simple JOIN, it will achieve the same thing and generally be just way better.

Basically your query would be like:

```
WITH list_of_ids AS (
   SELECT id FROM table_with_ids
)

SELECT main_table.*
FROM main_table 
JOIN list_of_ids
   ON main_table.id = list_of_ids.id
```

I think it is pretty clean syntax and solves your problem. 
Let me know if there is something I am missing and I can add to this.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to what Francesco says, if you really want to use it as a variable, actually it is also possible and probably not expensive at all.

```
DECLARE ListOfIds ARRAY<INT64> DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(Id) FROM ...);

SELECT
  *
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  Id IN UNNEST(ListOfIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH ListOfIds AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(Id) ids
  FROM ...
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(ids) 
FROM ...
,ListOfIds
WHERE id IN UNNEST(ListOfIds.ids)
```

[Super] Simplified example for testing/playing with above is :

```
#standardSQL
WITH ListOfIds AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(Id) ids
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) id
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(ids) 
FROM UNNEST([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]) id
,ListOfIds
WHERE id IN UNNEST(ids)
```

with output

```
Row id   
1   1    
2   3    
3   5
```

Comment: forgot to mention - unless you really have good reason for what you asked - I would recommend JOIN as it recommended by Francesco-Paolo-Galletta. The reason me saying this is I can see the only reason of your original ask is to have less verbose query in not to clutter it with all thos JOINs and ON clauses etc. If you have different reason - please share your use case